# Remove outline from image on transparent form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to transfer window form into transparent, and make it show just an object. But it still has a line (stroke) around my object, it's not really perfect as I wanted. How can I take out the line (stroke)? (Attached a picture to compare.)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.Width = this.pictureBox1.Width;
    this.Height = this.pictureBox1.Height;
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    this.BackColor = Color.Black;
    this.TransparencyKey = this.pictureBox1.BackColor;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this has more to do with the image than in code, the image itself has the outline

Comment: Can you post detail about the image format? So we can know if it support alpha channel, that would be the most likely cause of your edge problem with this picture without proper alpha channel like in a png file. Anti aliasing will never render properly. Anti aliasing is what you need to blend in curved edges with backgrounds in the case of a transparent background you need alpha to have a semi transparent opacity on the edge to achieve that simply cause you can't know what the background will be.

Comment: Yes, the format file is .png. and I've took it from internet. http://www.pngmart.com/image/16212

Comment: Most likely the border pixels are semi-transparent. TransparencyKey will not support that. You need to delete them or fill them to alpha=255. If you need a routine to do that say so..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image has semi-transparent pixels. `TransparencyKey`  will only make **one** color transparent. So the borderline pixels will show a mix of the image color and the color of the `Parent` control or form..

Here is a function that eliminates all semi-transparent pixels by making them fully transparent:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
..

public static void UnSemi(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Size s = bmp.Size;
    PixelFormat fmt = bmp.PixelFormat;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, s);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, fmt);
    int size1 = bmpData.Stride * bmpData.Height;
    byte[] data = new byte[size1];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, data, 0, size1);
    for (int y = 0; y < s.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < s.Width; x++)
        {
            int index = y * bmpData.Stride + x * 4;
             // alpha,  threshold = 255
            data[index + 3] = (data[index + 3] < 255) ? (byte)0 : (byte)255; 
        }
    }
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
}
```

Note that this also means that the nice anti-aliased look will get somewhat rough instead..

Also note that the routine assumes a 32 bit ARGB pixel-format, as `PNGs` will usually have.

Finally note that since the image has a **lot** of `Black` you should pick a different color. `Fuchsia` is rather rare in the wild, but maybe not in the world of dragons and you want to pick some random color..

Also: You want to set the `pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent`..

Finally: Sometimes it makes sense to add a `threshold` parameter to the function signature to set a level from which to turn alpha all on or off..

Here is a usage example:

```
this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1,2,3,4);
this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;
UnSemi((Bitmap)this.pictureBox1.Image);
```

[image]

Comment: Still can't. I've tried even a circle shape with transparent, and nothing changed. :(

Comment: If you don't mind, you can create one quickly in c#, and then send me that file? So I can see it. Thanks.

Comment: I did tried it. Although it's not really as perfect as I'd like it to be, but this code is very helpful. Thanks for your help. You're awesome! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use Png Image Which Has transparent background
set Your Control/Form Background color and transparent Key To Color That Doesn't Exist In the Image

Comment: I did, but it's the same problem. Nothing changed.